Right sidebar box missing padding under headers
There should probably be padding under the headers - can it be re-added? I'm using Firefox on Windows 11, and I can reproduce this both signed in and when signed out (with userscripts & uBlock Origin disabled).



This has also affected the controls on the right hand side of the flag dashboard (TL chatroom message link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66734554#66734554 )

Thanks for reporting, there's a couple broken things with all the right sidebar headers — fix coming shortly.

Does SE not have a staging area where changes are tested before being implemented live?

@AndrewLeach There is a staging area that's used. This issue is related to a Stacks version mismatch (our design system). I'll try and get all the details and share in an answer once it's fixed.

@Carrott sorry but the comment doesn't make much sense for me. You answered only part of the comment you replied to (the "Does SE not have a staging area") but did not answer the main question which is "are changes being tested before being implemented live?".

Contrary to popular belief, changes do get tested before being implemented live. Sorry if that wasn't clear. @ShadowWizard

@Carrott indeed, it wasn't said in your previous reply. Anyway, glad it does get tested.

Yesterday (or close to it, depending on your timezone), an update in our core codebase that included a new version of our design system, Stacks, was shipped. This dependency update required changes to our markup that were not yet fully implemented. We’ve rolled back to a previous version of our design system which should resolve any strange padding and border issues with sidebar widgets.
This rollback may take a moment to be reflected while changes propagate. Thanks for the patience while the teams worked on getting this issue resolved.
If you are still experiencing this issue, please clear your browser's cache, or perform a hard refresh of the page on your browser.
For those that are interested, here's a short timeline overview of what happened

Core team A needed a new component in the latest version of our
design system, Stacks
Core team A had a larger feature branch working with the latest
version to be able to use that component
That same Stacks release also had changes to the sidebar widgets that
required markup changes in Core (different component)
All at the same time, Stacks was in the process of testing the latest
version — which had been released in Stacks but not applied to core
code yet
Core Team A released the feature that included latest and greatest
from Stacks — stricter requirement for component markup to follow a
defined structure.
At the same time, there also happened to be another Core Team B
working on experiments on the homepage (including right sidebars).
Bad luck on timing for where in the process Stacks was with releases
(internal done but not set to core yet) and what other teams were
working on.


Still not working on most sites, e.g. on Movies. How long can this "moment" be?

You may need to clear your cache - checking the site in an incognito browser window, it appears to be working as intended.
